# Invalid pointer for Delphi 2009 Com dll project

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009

I am upgrading from Delphi 7 on Windows XP to Delphi 2009 on Windows vista and I get invalid pointer operation after successfully loading a delphi dll project in com dll preject. Debuging the problem happen in Aftercontruction of by object that call the loadlibrary. please advise.

Answer (score 4):

are you trying to create a new project or is it an old project which you upgraded and tried to run?

Just a guess if it is an old project which suddenly stops working on Vista: make sure the program has all the **access rights** it needs! That once was the cause of weird errors in one of my programs. It worked in XP but had funny errors in Vista because there was no manifest telling it needed admin rights. The missing rights caused parts of the software to fail silently.

Before making more tests please ensure the program has all the access rights it needs.

Heinrich

Answer (score 3):

*Invalid pointer operation* means you're trying to free something that the current module's memory manager has no record of. There are three possibilities:

- It was never allocated at all.
- It was allocated but has already been freed once.
- It was allocated by another module's memory manager.